# What is the best Font with less empty Space (ultra fat)

Tags: fonts

I search a good looking font which has **small empty space**, means the characters are full and nearly quadratic.

*Or in other words, if you draw a rectangle or quadre around a letter, nearly 80 % should be filled with the character, only small empty space.*

The best i got so far is **Frutiger Ultra bold**, but it still wastes too much space.

Letterspacing can be altered so its not priority.

Comment: I think [fat is a technical term](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/keyword/fat). Also [here](http://www.abstractfonts.com/font/11938) says something about being free

Comment: Try http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/canadatype/neil-bold/ or http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/hvdfonts/bumper/regular/

Comment: @egreg yes, thx 4 the hint. in such cases do i have to delete this question here if i decide to post it there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leo Liu suggested [Neil Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/canadatype/neil-bold/) and [Bumper](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/hvdfonts/bumper/regular/).

Also [Ultra Fat](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/ultra-fat/), [Ryno Slab](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/philatype/ryno-slab/), [Rita](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/sudtipos/rita/), [Cuadrifonte](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/pintassilgo/cuadrifonte/), [Akimoto](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/hiekkagraphics/akimoto/), [Yume](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/thinkdust/yume/), [Grim](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/rekord/grim/), [Loudine](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/pintassilgo/loudine/), [Tonal](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/pintassilgo/tonal/), [Grafinc](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/poster-type/grafinc/), [Fatta](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/los-andes/fatta/) may well do, and probably many more.

[Dimensions](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/flat-it/dimensions/) probably fits the 80% criterion too.